# Неправильная работа с массивами передаваемыми по ссылке

Tags: java

Я создал форму ввода данных javafx.
Контроллер использует паттерн Instance для удобства работы с несколькими окнами (через них я редактирую записи в таблицах главного окна)

```
public class InputController implements Initializable {
    public static ObservableList<Student> students = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public static ObservableList<Professor> professors = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private static InputController instance;
    public static HashMap<String, Professor> resource;
    public ArrayBlockingQueue<Student> threads;
    public static int quant;

    //применяем паттерн Instance
    public static InputController getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new InputController();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @FXML
    void startExam() throws Exception {
        //коллекция студентов - потоков
        threads = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(students.size());
        for (Student student : students) {
            Student thread = new Student(student.getName(), student.getPrioritet(), student.getBurst(), student.getTasks());
            thread.setName(student.getNameStudent());
            threads.add(thread);
        }
        FCFS alg = new FCFS(threads, resource);
        alg.schedule();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        defaultData();
    }
    //значения по умолчанию
    private void defaultData() {
        Professor newProfessor = new Professor("p1", 1);
        professors.add(newProfessor);
        newProfessor = new Professor("p2", 1);
        professors.add(newProfessor);
        ArrayList<String> predmetsAll = new ArrayList<String>();
        predmetsAll.add("p1");
        predmetsAll.add("p2");
        ArrayList<String> predmetsCastom1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        predmetsCastom1.add("p2");
        ArrayList<String> predmetsCastom2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        predmetsCastom2.add("p2");
        Student student = new Student("Студент-1", 1, 2, predmetsAll);
        students.add(student);
        student = new Student("Студент-2", 10, 3, predmetsCastom1);
        students.add(student);
        student = new Student("Студент-3", 2, 3, predmetsCastom2);
        students.add(student);
    }
}
```

Далее алгоритм обработки объектов (менеджер FCFS) в конструктор которого я передал очередь threads созданную в InputController с помощью коллекции объектов ObservableList students. То есть не передаю students, а создаю новую очередь с объектами в цикле

```
threads = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(students.size());
        for (Student student : students) {
            Student thread = new Student(
                    student.getName(), 
                    student.getPrioritet(), 
                    student.getBurst(), 
                    student.getTasks()
            );
            thread.setName(student.getNameStudent());
            threads.add(thread);
        }
```

Непосредственно сам FCFS

```
public class FCFS implements Algoritm {
        private ArrayBlockingQueue<Student> threads;
        private Student currentStudent;
        private static List<Student> finishedTasks = new ArrayList<>();
```

public FCFS() {
}

```
        public FCFS(ArrayBlockingQueue<Student> threads, HashMap<String, Professor> resource) {
            this.threads = threads;
            this.resource = resource;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void schedule() throws InterruptedException {
            String currentTask = null;
            long timeAlgoritm = 0;
            int sizeAllWork = threads.size();
            while(finishedTasks.size() < sizeAllWork) {
                int counter = 0;
                currentStudent = threads.take();
                if (currentStudent.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
                    currentStudent.start();
                }
                if (currentStudent.getStatus().equals("ready")) {
                    currentTask = currentStudent.getTasks().get(counter);
                    while (true) {
                        if (resource.get(currentTask).getSemaforPetri().close()) {
                            currentStudent.setWork(counter, currentStudent.getBurst());
                            currentStudent.setStatus("work");
                            threads.put(currentStudent);
                            break;
                        } else {
                            if (counter + 1 <= currentStudent.getTasks().size() - 1) {
                                counter++;
                                currentTask = currentStudent.getTasks().get(counter);
                            } else {
                                currentStudent.setStatus("wait");
                                threads.put(currentStudent);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (currentStudent.getStatus().equals("dead")) {
                    currentStudent.interrupt();
                    finishedTasks.add(currentStudent);
                } else threads.put(currentStudent);
            }
            for (Student thread : finishedTasks) {
                if (thread.getWorkTimeThread() > timeAlgoritm) {
                    timeAlgoritm = thread.getWorkTimeThread();
                }
                System.out.println(thread.getName() + ": "  + thread.getLogMap().entrySet());
            }
        }
    }
```

Поток Student в какой то момент редактирует свое состояние - удаляет выполненную задачу из списка задач (tasks.remove(taskIndex))

```
public class Student extends Thread {
    private ArrayList<String> tasks;
    private String nameStudent, status;
    private int burst, prioritet, time, taskIndex, workTime, currentBurst;
    private LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> logMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public Student(String nameStudent, int prioritet, int burst, ArrayList<String> tasks) {
        this.nameStudent = nameStudent;
        this.prioritet = prioritet;
        this.burst = burst;
        this.prioritet = prioritet;
        this.burst = burst;
        this.tasks = tasks;
        this.time = 0;
        this.status = "ready";
        this.currentBurst = burst;
    }
    .... геттеры и сеттеры
    private void workResorce() {
        while (workTime != 0) {
            try {
                sleep(quant);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            logMap.put(time, status + "(" + tasks.get(taskIndex) + ")");
            setTime(time + quant);
            currentBurst = workTime - quant;
            workTime = workTime - quant;
        }
        resource.get(tasks.get(taskIndex)).getSemaforPetri().open();
        if (currentBurst <= 0) {
            **tasks.remove(taskIndex);**
            currentBurst = burst;
        }
        if (tasks.isEmpty()) {
            setStatus("dead");
        } else {
            setStatus("ready");
        }
    }
    
    private void waitResorce() {
      ....
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
            if (status.equals("work")) {
                System.out.println(getName() + " workTime " + workTime + " work " + tasks.get(taskIndex));
                workResorce();
            }
            if (status.equals("wait")) waitResorce();
        }
    }
}
```

Так вот, алгоритм FCFS отрабатывает по клику кнопки запускающей в контроллере startExam() правильно только 1 раз. А затем ему передаются неверные данные из контроллера, а именно список задач - массив ArrayList tasks в объекте Student становится пуст, то есть почему то изменяется ObservableList students. Ведь я же не передаю коллекцию students как ссылку, но почему-то коллекция threads созданная на ее основании работает как ссылка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в том что создавая новый объект Student в этом коде

```
threads = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(students.size());
        for (Student student : students) {
            Student thread = new Student(
                    student.getName(), 
                    student.getPrioritet(), 
                    student.getBurst(), 
                    student.getTasks()
            );
            thread.setName(student.getNameStudent());
            threads.add(thread);
        }
```

я передавал в него не массив, а ссылку. То есть я создал новый объект и это было правильно, но я не создал новый массив задач в нем. После изменения student.getTasks() на инициализацию нового массива все стало работать нормально. Спасибо MaxRokatansky за [статью](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/551026/). Эта ошибка видна из вопроса и возможно кому то будет полезно это (минус за что?).